# Nginx not forwarding URL's correctly

Tags: nginx

First of all this may not be the problem but even so I didn't know how to title this post.

I have a set up which redirects every url which is in the format `xxxx.ops.internal.com` after authentication to the corresponding URL.

If I visit the URL `example.ops.internal.com` then I will be taken to `example.ops.internal.com` however if I visit `foobar.ops.internal.com` I am also taken to the contents provided by `example.ops.internal.com` if that makes sense.

It seems that no matter what URL I use, the content for `example.ops.internal.com` is returned.

This is the config:

```
server {
   listen *:8081;
   server_name example.ops.*;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://hiddenip;
        proxy_redirect  off;
   }
}

server {
   listen *:8081;
   server_name foobar.ops.*;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://hiddenip2;
        proxy_redirect  off;
   }
}
```

It seems that the content for the first server is always returned.

This is how the authentication takes place and the redirect happens:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name ~^auth.(?<domain>ops.*)$;
  location = /oauth2/callback {
    proxy_pass http://google-auth;
  }

  location ~/(?<sub>[^/]+)(?<remaining_uri>.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ https://$sub.$domain$remaining_uri;
  }
}
```

Maybe some headers aren't being passed correctly?

Edit:

This is basically my configuration [Bitly Oauth2 application](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy/issues/12) which shows the authentication app which has `port :8081` as the upstream.

`nginx :80 -> oauth app (using Bitly Oauth2 app) -> nginx :8081 -> requested_route`

Is the simplified application flow.

Comment: `org` or `ops`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Sorry it was meant to say `ops` not `org`. The problem still remains though.

Comment: I don't see where you request port 8081

Comment: @AlexeyTen if got a separate authentication app which has :8081 as its upstream if ports are authenticated. if you click the link that I've added, that is what my set up is.

Comment: Then show it. Most probably, you've lost `Host` header somewhere.

Comment: @AlexeyTen The app is quite large and not written by me so I cant post all the code on here, there is a link to the config that is 'supposed' to work based on other users experiences. The main point is once you are authenticated it forwards the request to port `:8081`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Checking the Nginx logs and the `$http_host` variable and the header seems to have the correct data

Answer (score 0):

The `Host` header was not being correctly forwarded to the oauth application thus never to upstreams. This config was needed on the main `:80` server:

```
location  / {
    proxy_pass http://google-auth;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
```